# Tuple for multiprocessing.Array in python

Tags: python, arrays, multiprocessing

I'm struggling with multiprocessing in python.
I want to put list of tuple in multiprocessing.Array, but I can't find the typecode for tuple.

This is the code, and I want to know how to write "type_of_tuple" for arr in main function.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array

def thread_func(time, array):
    time.sleep(time)
    if len(array) > 0:
        print(array.pop(0))

def main(cpu_number):
    list = [("a","b"), ("c","d"), ("e","f")]
    arr = Array( type_of_tuple """ how to write this?""", list)

    for i in range(cpu_number):
        r = pool.apply_async(thread_func, args=(1000, arr))
        thread_list.append(r)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(3)
```

Comment: what is `type_of_tuple`?

Comment: Sorry, it is I want to know... Array required type of each item in list. I have to write something in place of "type_of_tuple"...

Comment: As a side note, don't call a variable `list`; that hides the name of the type/constructor, which you may want to use later.

Comment: Also, it's very confusing to call the result of `apply_async` a "thread", when it's actually a future-like result object.

Comment: Thanks for the advise! You're right. I'll mind later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you can't find it is because it doesn't exist. The whole point of `Array` is that it handles arrays of simple, homogenous types that can be stored as "unboxed" binary data.

A tuple is a compound type, which can hold any number of values of any kind. So you can't put it in an `Array`.

In fact, you can't put strings in arrays either, because strings have a variable number of characters; each one is a different size. (And, if this is Python 3, it's even worse than that, because characters can be 1, 2, or 4 bytes…)

On top of that, an array has a fixed length; you can't `pop` values off it anyway.

So, you will need to find a different way to share this data.

You could use `shared_ctypes` if you understand C well enough to map your tuple of strings to a `struct` of `char*`.

Or you could write a function to encode the tuples into fixed-size values (which you then slice into an Array of characters) on one side and decode them on the other.

But I suspect you'll find life a lot simpler if you do what the docs recommend and find a way to write your code in terms of message passing instead of shared memory.

Since the only shared mutation you need to here is to have each job `pop` a value off the end so that other jobs won't see the same value, the obvious answer is to use a `Queue`, because that's exactly what it does.

Or, even simpler, just use one of the higher-level methods like `map` instead of `apply`, to take care of managing the queue and making sure each job gets exactly one value, so you don't even have to think about it. For example:

```
def thread_func(time, value):
    time.sleep(time)
    print(value)

def main(cpu_number):
    values = [("a","b"), ("c","d"), ("e","f")]
    results = pool.imap_unordered(partial(thread_func, 1000), values[:cpu_number])
    for result in results:
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(3)
```

(As a side note, I'm not sure why you're restricting the number of tasks to the number of CPUs. Normally, you create a `Pool(cpu_number)` and just queue up all of the tasks on that. If you only want to run exactly 3 tasks, you don't even really need a pool for that, just run each one on a `Process`.)

Comment: Thank you for your thorough explanation! I have only little knowledge for multiprocessing, so I have to study it before using.

Comment: @ArataKokubun I agree with abarnert that using `map` is the best option in this case. But just as an FYI, if you really did need to change the `values` list in each worker process for some reason, using  `m = multiprocessing.Manager ; values = m.list([("a","b"), ("c","d"), ("e","f")])` would create a special list that can be shared between processes, allowing you to call `pop`, reassign items, etc in each worker. Read more about how that works [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#managers). Note that there is a performance penalty when using shared objects, though.

Comment: @dano: Every time I've started off thinking `Manager` was going to make my life easier, I ran into a roadblock somewhere down the line and had to dive into the pipe underneath. But then I was usually trying to register custom classes; maybe with just `list` or `dict` it's a different story. Anyway, +1 for pointing it out; it's worth learning all of the different ways to do things.

Comment: @abarnert The only major headaches I've had with the objects actually included in `SyncManager` is dealing with mutable objects inside of proxies for mutable object (i.e. a list of lists). The docs do have a note which warns that changing mutable objects inside mutable proxies won't get propagated, but its a pain in any case.

Comment: @dano: Yeah, but I'd already learned to deal with that with libraries like `shelve` before trying to use `Manager`. I guess it's not surprising that different people run into different stumbling blocks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, without caring about the logic, you should use a ctypes struct instead:

```
from ctypes import Structure, POINTER, byref, c_ubyte, cast, create_string_buffer
from multiprocessing import Pool, Array


class SomeTuple(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ('a', POINTER(c_ubyte)),
        ('b', POINTER(c_ubyte))
    ]


def thread_func(time, array_):
    time.sleep(time)
    if len(array_) > 0:
        print(array_.pop(0))

def main(cpu_number):
    thread_list = []
    value_list = [
        SomeTuple(cast(create_string_buffer(b"a"), POINTER(c_ubyte)), cast(create_string_buffer(b"b"), POINTER(c_ubyte))),
        SomeTuple(cast(create_string_buffer(b"c"), POINTER(c_ubyte)), cast(create_string_buffer(b"d"), POINTER(c_ubyte))),
        SomeTuple(cast(create_string_buffer(b"e"), POINTER(c_ubyte)), cast(create_string_buffer(b"f"), POINTER(c_ubyte)))
    ]
    arr = Array(SomeTuple, value_list)

    with Pool(processes=cpu_number) as pool:
        for _ in range(cpu_number):
            r = pool.apply_async(thread_func, args=(1000, arr))
            thread_list.append(r)

    for thread in thread_list:
        thread.wait()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(3)
```

Comment: Since all of his strings are single-character, you could probably get away with skipping the `create_string_buffer` stuff… but it's probably better to do what you did, and show him the fully complexity, than to take shortcuts that may not be appropriate in his real code.

Comment: However, even with all this, it's still not going to work, because you can't call `pop` on an `Array`. They're fixed-size arrays. The best you can do is pass around an `Array` and a length or offset `Value('i')`. (In general, that also means you need a `Lock` to synchronize the two, but since the only mutation he's doing is incrementing the `offset`, never touching the `Array` itself, that isn't needed here.)